# Selected Locator in Mobile Object does not appear (Katalon)

Tags: android, object, mobile, selected, katalon

Why the selected locator in object (mobile apk testing) does not appear or does not exist

Hi, i am writing katalon script for mobile android testing. I found button object, i wanted to spy it. When i spy the button object, the object has selected locator, attributs etc that usually appear when spy object in katalon. But when i save the button object, the selected locator does not appear. What happen with the button object? and what should i do? Please help me.
Thank you

i spy the object more than once and using another device. I am using katalon 8.6.8